# lightning:empApi and Callout: Streaming API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, api, callout, platform-event

I created a test platform event with checkbox, added my custom object to Change Data Capture and did this:

**empAPI.cmp:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
        <!-- A part of my page -->
        <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />
        <aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Map"/>

        <lightning:input aura:id="channel" label="channel" name="channel" type="text" value="/event/TestEvent__e"/>
        <lightning:button label="Subscribe" onclick="{!c.subscribe}" variant="brand"/>
        <lightning:button label="Unubscribe" onclick="{!c.unsubscribe}" disabled="{!empty(v.subscription)}" variant = "destructive"/>
    </aura:component>
```

**empAPIController.js:**

```
({
        onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
            const empApi = component.find('empApi');
            empApi.setDebugFlag(true);
            empApi.onError($A.getCallback(error => {
                console.error('EMP API error: ', error);
            }));
        },

        subscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
            const empApi = component.find('empApi');
            const channel = component.find('channel').get('v.value');
            const replayId = -1;
            empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(eventRecieved => {
                console.log('Recieved event ', JSON.stringify(eventRecieved));
            })).then(subscription => {
                console.log('Subscription to channel ', subscription.channel);
                component.set('v.subscription', subscription);
            });     
        },

        unsubscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
            const empApi = component.find('empApi');
            const subscription = component.get('v.subscription');
            empApi.unsubscribe(subscription, $A.getCallback(unsubscribed => {
                console.log('Unsubscribed from channel ' + unsubscribed.subscription);
                component.set('v.subscription', null);
            }))
        },
    })
```

In Execute Anonimous Window I have:

```
    TestEvent__e testEvent = new TestEvent__e();
    testEvent.Modified__c = true;  //My checkbox
    EventBus.publish(testEvent);
```

It works: I see it in my console.

Now. I have **Callout**:

```
public static void createTasks(){
        List<CustomTask__c> newCardsList = new List<CustomTask__c>();

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('MyApiCall');
        request.setMethod('GET'); 
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

        List<Object> receivedCards = (List<Object>) results.get('cards');

        for(Object eachCard : receivedCards){
            String cardInText = String.valueOf(eachCard);
            String name = cardInText.substringBetween('), name=', '}');
            String description = cardInText.substringBetween('desc=', ',');

            CustomTask__c newCard = new CustomTask__c(
                Name__c = name,
                Description__c = description,
            );
            newCardsList.add(newCard);
        } 
        try {
            upsert newCardsList CardId__c;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

If I reload my Lightning page, a record of my custom object will upsert. But I need it without page reloading. How can I connect the functionality of Callout and `lightning:empApi`? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from your code

```
<lightning:input aura:id="channel" label="channel" name="channel" type="text" value="/event/TestEvent__e"/>
```

You are subscribing to the wrong event. CDC Events are streamed on `/data/<Custom_Object_Name>__ChangeEvent`

Thus in Your case as you are upserting `CustomTask__c` you code will be

```
<lightning:input aura:id="channel" label="channel" name="channel" type="text" value="/data/CustomTask__ChangeEvent"/>
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_channels.htm

Comment: The problem is, I still get my new record only after page reloading.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. I still try to run event with `TestEvent__e testEvent = new TestEvent__e();`. I shouldn't, right? If we use `/data/<Custom_Object_Name>__ChangeEvent`. But then how to provoke its launch? I use API of a third-party resource.

Comment: And is it even possible to set up `empApi` for streaming integration with third party service? Maybe I need some another tool...

Comment: @MichaelLev19 you wanna capture CDC event or custom `TestEvent__e` event?